# Replace Dell760 built-in NIC by another one

Tags: windows-xp, network-adapter

My Dell-760 Desktop buit-in NIC is failed and i purchased another NIC and i built but my machine doesn't detect. I also disabled the built-in NIC on Bios but still doesn't detect. How can i make my machine detect the new NIC?

Comment: There are 4 form factors for the 760, which do you have? Mini Tower, Desktop,  Small form factor, or Ultra small form factor? You can find PCI devices in the bios under System Configuration > Miscellaneous Devices

Comment: Are you sure the on-board NIC is actually (physically) broken?  I'm thinking maybe the thing that makes you think your on-board NIC is broken is also what's preventing your new NIC from being detected properly.  Perhaps test it in a temporary Linux install via a LiveCD?

Comment: @techie007 yes i have tested the NIC using Ubuntu live CD but it doesn't work. @Moab i'm using Desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick one...In the BIOS, goto Onboard Devices > PCI slots > make sure it is set to 'ON'.

Of course I'm assuming the new NIC card was PCI?

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious things to check are that you have properly installed the card.

- Is it fully seated in the expansion slot?
- Are any power leads connected? Unlikely I know, but you never know.

If that's the case then you could force the new hardware wizard to look for new hardware.